# How to expect one function to call another function?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to mock a function call, and expect it to have called another function within it once.

myFunctions.test.js

```
import { resetModal } from '../myFunctions.js';

describe('resetModal', () => {
  it('calls the clearSomethingInModal function', () => {
    const clearSomethingInModal = jest.fn();
    resetModal();
    expect(clearSomethingInModal.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
  })
})
```

myFunctions.js

```
export resetModal() {
  clearSomethingInModal()
}
```

However, Jest output says that it has not been called.  How can I best do this?

Comment: If both `resetModal` and `clearSomethingInModal` are exported from the same module, you can mock one and test the other. See https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/936

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Your approach does not work because you mock `clearSomethingInModal` only in the context of your test file, so `clearSomethingInModal` in the `myFunctions.js` is still the original. The main point is that you can't mock something that is directly created in  `myFunctions.js`. The only thing that you can mock are:

1. Modules that you import to `myFunctions.js`, like `import clearSomethingInModal from 'clearSomethingInModal'`;
2. Callbacks that you pass into your function when calling them from your test;

This makes sense if you think about `myFunctions.js` as a blackbox, where you can control what goes in, like imports or function arguments, and where you can test what comes out. But you can not test the stuff that happens inside the box.

Here are two example that reflect the 2 points in the list:

myFunctions.test.js

```
import { resetModal } from '../myFunctions.js';
import clearSomethingInModal from 'clearSomethingInModal';

jest.mock('clearSomethingInModal', () => jest.fn())

describe('resetModal', () => {
  it('calls the clearSomethingInModal function', () => {
    resetCreationModal();
    expect(clearSomethingInModal.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
  })
})
```

myFunctions.js

```
import clearSomethingInModal from 'clearSomethingInModal';

export resetModal() {
  clearSomethingInModal()
}
```

---

myFunctions.test.js

```
import { resetModal } from '../myFunctions.js';

describe('resetModal', () => {
  it('calls the clearSomethingInModal function', () => {
    const clearSomethingInModal = jest.fn();
    resetCreationModal(clearSomethingInModal);
    expect(clearSomethingInModal.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
  })
})
```

myFunctions.js

```
export resetModal(clearSomethingInModal) {
  clearSomethingInModal()
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andreas, that's a great explanation.  So i take it that without changing the structure of my function, i cannot test in the way I want.  So, (a) would that imply an issue in the design of the function, and (b), in it's current form, would there be any valid tests that you could apply to it ?  Note that the 'resetModal' function also calls a number of other functions within it that i have omited for brevity

Comment: but can't we just insert a spy function so that we can mock inner functions?

Comment: Where does `resetCreationModal()` come from? Shouldn't it be `resetModal(...)`?

Comment: @bytrangle yes I think that was just a mistake in the name by the author of the answer

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to use `done` and mock or spy on the implementation of the last function and check if the previous function was called by then.

```
it('should call function2 after function1', (done) => {
    expect.assertions(2)

    function2.mockImplementationOnce(() => {
      expect(function1).toHaveBeenCalled()
      done()
    })

    act() // This is where you run function you are testing
  })
```

The drawback of this solution is that the structure of the test is not

```
// arrange
// act
// assert
```

but rather

```
// arrange & assert
// act
```