# How to assert a function is called from within another function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, frontend

I have a component in React with an onChange event. In the code below, I need to assert that the correct method is called when

```
this.props.onChangeImage()
```

is invoked in the Gallery component.

```
export class Form extends React.PureComponent {

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.props.getUser();
    this.props.getImages();
    this.props.getBoards();
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.pin === null) {
      let boards = [];
      boards = this.props.boards;
      boards = boards.data.map(
        (item) => <MenuItem key={item.id.toString()} value={item.name} primaryText={item.name} />
      );
      return (
        <div>
          <Helmet
            title="Form"
            meta={[
              { name: 'description', content: 'Description of Form' },
            ]}
          />
          <Gallery images={this.props.images} onChange={this.props.onChangeImage} />
        </div>
      );
    }
    return (<div className="spinner-container"><CircularProgress /></div>);
  }
}
```

Below, in the onChangeImage method, I am trying to assert that the sendEventToParentWindow method is called.

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {

    onChangeImage: (event) => {
      dispatch(createPinImage(event.target.value));
      sendEventToParentWindow({
        action: 'change-image',
        description: 'Change image',
      });
    },
  };
}

function sendEventToParentWindow(message) {
  window.postMessage(message, window.location.href);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Form);
```

I've looked at a number of answers here, and while this one seemed closest, it's not quite getting me there: [Jest - mocking a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40771520/jest-mocking-a-function-call)

EDIT: Here is my test which I believe is wrong because it's assigning the mocked function to be called directly onChange when it really should be calling the function that in turn calls the mock. I need somehow to invoke the onImageChange function and then verify that my spy was called.

```
import Gallery from '../index';
import * as formIndex from '../../../containers/Form';

describe('<Gallery />', () => {
  it('Expect sendMessageToParentWindow to be called on image change', () => {
    const sendEventToParentWindowMock = jest.spyOn(formIndex, 'sendEventToParentWindow');
    const gallery = shallow(<Gallery images={imagesMockData} onChange={sendEventToParentWindowMock} />);
    gallery.find('input#image-1').simulate('change');

    expect(sendEventToParentWindowMock).toBeCalled();
  });
}
```

Comment: Which testing library are you using? Enzyme? If yes then are you shallow rendering the component?

Comment: @HardikModha, I do have Enzyme available to me and have tried shallow rendering and mounting the component. I didn't have any luck, but I am still learning and tinkering. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: You can pass the mocked function (whose implementation contains a mock method call) as prop when you are shallow rendering the component.

Comment: @HardikModha That seems to have done the trick. I was really close to the problem but just hadn't quite made it. Thank you! I'm build some tests with some other components and will repot back if I have any other questions. If all goes well, I'll post my answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it helped you. :)

Comment: Well, it definitely got me closer to understanding the problem. I've added an edit above which includes the test. I believe the test is wrong, but I'm closer than I was.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, You can pass a mocked function as prop whose implementation will contain a call to your `sendEventToParentWindow` function. i.e. You'll need to create two mocked function.

1. `sendEventToParentWindow` mock function.
2. `onChangeImage` mock function with implementation, where implementation will only contain call to your `sendEventToParentWindow` mock function.

So the test will look something like this,

```
describe('<Gallery />', () => {
  it('Expect sendMessageToParentWindow to be called on image change', () => {
    const sendEventToParentWindowMock = jest.fn();
    const onChangeImageMock = jest.fn(() => {
         sendEventToParentWindowMock();
    });

    const gallery = shallow(<Gallery images={imagesMockData} onChange={onChangeImageMock} />); // Passing the mocked onChangeImage as prop
    gallery.find('input#image-1').simulate('change');

    expect(sendEventToParentWindowMock).toBeCalled();
  });
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: That's the piece of understanding I was missing! I'll give this a try on Monday when I get back to the office, but thanks again for your patience and example code! It really helps to be able to see a solid example.

Comment: That was the missing bit! Thanks again. I've accepted the answer.