# How to mock a function type in typescript using jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, web, jestjs

I have a interface which contains [function types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#function-types), like following:

```js
interface MyInterface {
  (a: string, b: string): Promise<SomeType>;
  someFunction(a: string): Promise<SomeType>;
}
```

Let's say the interface is in a module `m`.

When I use it, I do things like:

```
import MyInterface from m;

function foo() {
  return MyInterface('abc', 'def');
}
```

I know that if I want to test how many times is `someFunction` called, I can use `jest.spyon`, like this:

```
import MyInterface from m;

const myMock = jest.spyon(MyInterface, 'someFunction');

...

expect(myMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

But how should I test the function type, if I want to know how many times it is called and with what parameters? The difficulty is that **it does not have a name**. It is like an anonymous function. I cannot to similar things like I did with `someFunction`.

How should I do it, please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mocking a function call in Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40771520/mocking-a-function-call-in-jest)

Comment: An interface cannot be used as a value in your code, only for type annotations

Comment: @krismath I wanna say no? Because the tricky part I am facing is that my function does not have a a name.

Comment: @AlexD Could you elaborate? I am sorry but I am pretty new to the field. Where did I try to use the interface as a value? And what is type annotation?

Comment: I think you probably don't understand the relationship between typescript and javascript. This question you asked is not typescript related. I suggest remove the wrong tag.

Comment: The whole typescript `interface`, `type` things are called "type annotation". They exist only in design time (the phase when you write code in an editor). When it come to runtime, those things are stripped away. Your typescript code is transpiled to javascript before it can be executed.

Comment: Short answer is no you simply can't do it. But [this article](https://medium.com/@DavideRama/mock-spy-exported-functions-within-a-single-module-in-jest-cdf2b61af642) provide some thoughts which require you to modify your module export fashion. Worth reading.