# Mocking single function from a module which also calls it from another function, jest, typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I have module with two functions:

```
export const functionReturnsOne = () => {
    return 1;
};
export const functionReturnsTwo = () => {
    return functionReturnsOne() + functionReturnsOne();
};
```

Now I would like to mock `functionReturnsOne` but keep original `functionReturnsTwo`

Here is the test:

```
import { functionReturnsTwo, functionReturnsOne } from '../testModule';

jest.mock('../testModule', () => {
    const actualTestModule = jest.requireActual('../testModule');
    return {
        ...actualTestModule,
        functionReturnsOne: jest.fn()
    };
});

describe('testModule', () => {
    test('when functionReturnsOne is mocked but functionReturnsTwo is not', () => {
        const mockFunctionReturnsOne = functionReturnsOne as jest.Mock;
        mockFunctionReturnsOne.mockReturnValue(13);

        const result1 = functionReturnsOne();
        const result2 = functionReturnsTwo();

        expect(result1).toBe(13);
        expect(result2).toBe(26);
    });
});
```

After running the test, `result1` contains `13` as expected, so mock for `functionReturnsOne` worked. But `result2` contains `2` which means this function called not mocked version of `functionReturnsOne`.

Is there elegant way (not splitting into separate files and no dependency injection) to call original `functionReturnsTwo` that would call mocked version of `functionReturnsOne`?

Comment: I think this answer would help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40780883/4315380

Comment: @tanmay Yeah, its refering to the same topic. Yet it does not solve the problem. You either have to put function in separate file to test it or do dependency injection. And I would rather not to that. Also I found another answer on github which suggest it is possible to mock single function. The problem is it does not work for me: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/936#issuecomment-545080082

Comment: According to this issue https://github.com/swc-project/swc/issues/3843 mocking single function is not possible with SpyOn (which was mentioned as possible solution in the link from previous comment)

Comment: it seems to have worked for me.. the suggestion on jest issue.. let me add an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the suggestion provided in [this comment](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/936#issuecomment-545080082), the following worked for me:

```
import * as testModule from "../testModule";

describe('test spyon with function expressions', function () {
  test('when there is no mock', () => {
    jest.spyOn(testModule, 'functionReturnsOne').mockReturnValue(13);

    const result1 = testModule.functionReturnsOne();
    const result2 = testModule.functionReturnsTwo();

    expect(result1).toBe(13);
    expect(result2).toBe(26);
  });
});
```

---

package.json (as requested)

```json
{
  "name": "cookbook",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A simple recipe app using typescript and sequelize",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "dev": "nodemon src/index.ts",
    "build": "npx tsc"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "sequelize",
    "typescript",
    "food",
    "recipes",
    "cache",
    "speed",
    "microdiff"
  ],
  "author": "ibywaks",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "microdiff": "^1.3.0",
    "mysql2": "^2.2.5",
    "node-cache": "^5.1.2",
    "sequelize": "^6.6.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.12",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.2",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.171",
    "@types/node": "^15.12.4",
    "@types/node-cache": "^4.2.5",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "eslint": "^7.30.0",
    "jest": "^27.2.4",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "supertest": "^6.1.6",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.5",
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.3.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be what I need but I've copy pasted your code and for me second ```expect``` returns ```2```. Could you please share your package.json with me? Can be in the answer itself.

Comment: updated the answer with package.json

Comment: hi @tanmay, what project did you use to make it work? I've tried that in React 16 project and it does not work for me. I know this is legit solution as it works for others as well (this link where you taken it from), just need to make it run on my side, then i can find the root cause why React 16 won't support this

Comment: @KubaK it was this: https://github.com/ibywaks/cookbook. I found it on the internet, cloned it and added code and test file and played around it there. Above code works there (didn't change any package version or anything else)

Answer (score 0):

As your are returning mock value only in function one, it is not necessary that the original functionTwo will get the mock inputs. Try this to mock functionTwo and have the desired response.

```
import { functionReturnsTwo, functionReturnsOne } from '../testModule';

jest.mock('../testModule', () => {
    const actualTestModule = jest.requireActual('../testModule');
    return {
        ...actualTestModule,
        functionReturnsOne: jest.fn()
    };
});

describe('testModule', () => {
    test('when there is no mock', () => {
        const mockFunctionReturnsOne = functionReturnsOne as jest.Mock;
        mockFunctionReturnsOne.mockReturnValue(13);

        const mockFunctionReturnsTwo = functionReturnsTwo as jest.Mock;
        mockFunctionReturnsTwo.mockReturnValue(functionReturnsOne() + 
                                                functionReturnsOne());
    
        const result1 = functionReturnsOne();
        const result2 = functionReturnsTwo();

        expect(result1).toBe(13);
        expect(result2).toBe(26);
    });
});
```

Comment: as I mentioned, I need to call original ```functionReturnsTwo```. In your example you are mocking ```functionReturnsTwo``` entirely. This way you are not really testing it, just calling the mock

Comment: You can not expect your original functionReturnsTwo to return mock expected outputs unless you make a new mock for functionReturnsTwo as your functionReturnsTwo depends on original functionReturnsOne and you are expecting mock outputs related to functionReturnsOne.

Comment: The thing is that you can. I've done it by exporting the function to a separate file, and then using ```jest.mock()``` on entire file directory. Now I need to get same result but without exporting function to a separate file.